# how do i set a specific domain which can use a ASMX service?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

I want to set my default Domain name for my site to be given access only by the webservices.

I'm using the webservices in JQuery Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this. In fact, it doesn't even make sense, once you think about it.

What will a web service be doing that is any different from what an arbitrary program could do using HTTP? How would your site distinguish between them?

Perhaps you can change your site to require authentication, then only give the credentials to users of the web service?

Comment: problem is, the url of the service is open in the Jquery AJAX code. isn't there a way that i can only specify that the request going to this service only allow the same domain it is using?

Comment: No. The domain is not part of the request,

Comment: ok, maybe ill just implement an authentication within the service. Thanks John for your excellent answer!